# What is the error with rake db:migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried executing this command

```
rake db:migrate
```

i keep getting the error:

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
You should not use the `match` method in your router without specifying an HTTP method.
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: run `rake db:migrate --trace` and try to debug it. If still stuck then post the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is rails 4 you should use get or post instead of match in your routes file. For example, make the following changes to your config/routes.rb file:

```
get 'your/:route' => 'your_controller#your_action'
post 'your/:route' => 'your_controller#your_action'
```